# Is there a way to do Dependency Injection of Graphql.EntityFramework with Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphql, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I'm attempting to integrate `GrapQL.EntityFramework` using a DB first approach on an Azure Function. I've generated the needed contexts, User graphs, query, along with the function itself. Currently I'm having an issue with the `Startup` file of my function app where I am to use dependency injection.

I've attempted both options on the configuration guide in the [GraphQL.EntityFramework Docs](https://github.com/SimonCropp/GraphQL.EntityFramework/blob/master/doco/configuration.md#dependencyinjection-and-aspnet-core). I've also made attempts at snippets of code such as `builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IEfGraphQLService<PersonarDBContext>),instance => { return new DBContext(); });`

The current state of my startup file

```cs
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
     string connection = ""
     builder.Services.AddTransient<UserQuery>();
     builder.Services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
     var optionBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DBContext>();
     optionBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);
     EfGraphQLConventions.RegisterInContainer<DBContext>(builder.Services, null);
     EfGraphQLConventions.RegisterConnectionTypesInContainer(builder.Services);
     builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IEfGraphQLService<DBContext>),instance => { return new DBContext(); });
}
```

At this point in time I am just attempting to get my function app to startup properly. I am currently experiencing this error output.

> User: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'User'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'service' to type IEfGraphQLService`1. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.).

Comment: you are trying to match differing types here `builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IEfGraphQLService<DBContext>),instance => { return new DBContext(); });`. Does `DbContext` derive from `IEfGraphQLService<DBContext>`? I highly doubt.

Comment: @Nkosi DB context isn't derived from the IEfGraphQLService, it uses the EntityFramework.Core DbContext

Comment: On removal of the last line I still receive the same error output

Answer (score 0):

Likely worth opening an [issue on GitHub](http://github.com/azure/azure-Functions-host) but my suspicion is whatever the library is trying to auto-register here is throwing the exception

```
EfGraphQLConventions.RegisterInContainer<DBContext>(builder.Services, null);
 EfGraphQLConventions.RegisterConnectionTypesInContainer(builder.Services);
```

Comment: From the looks of it I may have to, doesn't seem like there is too much support on DI. I was basically trying to approach the function app from a full c# application angle.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is the function DI is not a mirror of the ASP.NET DI pipeline provided there. It’s using the same abstractions and implementation, but sometimes libraries assume it will be used in ASP.NET and potentially rely on services or override aspects that won’t exist or can’t be overridden in a function. So the support is there, but do see lots of people bumping into compat issues trying to use DI code that works in ASP.NET within a function. If there’s a sample of using this library as part of a console app that may be a better reference point.